# How to get an object from a list of objects (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I know how to "translate" this into code:

if the `Cancellation.User.Id` **is** the same as `currentUser.Id`

```
if (cancellation.User.Id != currentUser.Id){...}
```

But what if my `Cancellation` object contains not one `User` but a `List<User> Users`?

How do I check if the `Cancellation` object **contains** a `User` whose `Id` is the same as `currentUser.Id`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Trying that now!
Well, this is another option I am trying, from a different angle.

Comment: It can be done without iteration, if you use a little LINQ. See my answer.

Comment: @anaximander has a better approch than me. So I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ will solve this quite nicely.

```
if (cancellation.Users.Any(u => u.ID == currentUser.Id)){...}
```

Note that this is true if there **is** a matching user in the list, which is what you said in your last sentence, but seems counter to the code snippet you provided, which is checking if the ID does **not** match. If you want to trigger this code if **none** of the users match, just put a `!` before the whole lot (not in the lambda).

Comment: You right. It is better than an iteration. `.Any` is well suited for this situation

Comment: did you mean `(u => u.ID == currentUser.Id)){...}`

Comment: How about this:  

`var all_cancellations = dc.Cancellations.Include("Course").Where(cancellation => cancellation.User.Id == currentUserId);`
Do I do change it like this?

`var all_cancellations = dc.Cancellations.Include("Course").Where(cancellation => cancellation.Users.Any(u => u.Id == currentUserId));`

Comment: Assuming I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do, yes, that looks fine.

Comment: (**Had to wait 5 minutes to edit this comment**) What I am trying to do is retrieve all the `Cancellation` objects from `DataContext` by `CurrentUser.Id`, taking into consideration that each `Cancellation` object has a `List<ApplicationUser> Users`.